# How to update mkdir in order to install express-generator without warnings?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I was going to install express-generator on windows computer. I used this
`npm install -g express-generator`
command in cmd and it gave me this
 **npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)** warning. Then I used
`npm install mkdirp@1`
and successfully installed **mkdirp@1.0.4** version. CMD confirmed it showing me this message 
**+ mkdirp@1.0.4
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 1.981s
found 0 vulnerabilities**
But unfoutunately when I try to reinstall express-generator using `npm install -g express-generator`, cmd shows me the same warning. Exactly the same warning. How Can I update mkdirp?? Help Me..

Comment: In this case, you can't. Because the mkdirp@0.5.1 is a dependency of express-generator package and when you install this package, npm will install all of it's dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's caused by generally access copyright;

you can avoid the access to modify directory by :

`$ sudo npm install -g express-generatoe@4.15.0`

or the latest version to install:

Comment: nicolas alien -technology - zone 51

Answer (score 1):

You can run the application generator with the npx command (available in Node.js 8.2.0).

```
$ npx express-generator
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run all this in window terminal CMD or powershell**

Step-1 update the mkdirp.

- $ npm install mkdirp@1* in CMD

Step-2 Install express globlly.

- $ npm i -g express-generator* in CMD

Now its works

Answer (score 0):

Try this command(from the official website):

```
npm install express --save
```

Comment: The question is about express-generator not express itself

Answer (score 0):

Use the application generator tool, express-generator, to quickly create an application skeleton.

You can run the application generator with the npx command (available in Node.js 8.2.0).

$ npx express-generator